# Wire with mysterious power

Tags: wire

I am currently swapping out my switches with smart switches and one of the switches had different wire setup from the usual.

Prior to taking out the switch I took picture of the "primary switch" I quated/ say that cause when removing switches wire both had power in both areas.

Main switch [image]
Look closely as the white wire and i believe the line wire are combined.

Secondary switch:
[image]

I got the switch currently working and the on and off works on the light. But could some one tell me if you can make it out in the images what that red wire Is?

New Main switch:
[image]

Comment: Light switches? Air-con switches? American? Australian? Not enough context.

Comment: @Transistor sorry. They are Light Switches. American

Comment: Look up 3-way switch on your favorite search engine's images.

Comment: @calcium3000 I did. It shows that red wire suppose to be a connection between light switches. But I have both red wires unplugged yet my voltage pen shows power

Comment: Do you have a multimeter to test it instead?  I wouldn't trust those voltage pens.  Are you sure those red wires are the only ones in the circuit?  They could be totally separate from the 2 switches you're messing with.  Also, this could be a question for the Home Improvement SE.

Comment: @calcium3000 I'm getting about 0.170v from that red one

Comment: @calcium3000 it powers a outdoor flood light and there are only 2 switches to turn it on

Comment: Okay, so what's your question?  That second sentence in your original post isn't too clear.  Does the 3-way switch answer it?

Comment: @calcium3000 well answer me this is the red wire that is coming from the same jacket as the switch in the other location according to diagrams supposed to only have connection between both switches?

Comment: @calcium3000 and not the light?

Comment: @calcium3000 and maybe the 0.170v just a trace of electricity because of electro magnetic field?

Comment: Put my answer below so that I could add an image.

Comment: And yes, that 0.17V is either coupled from the other wires or just noise from your DMM.

Answer (score 4):

That red wire is most likely part of a 3-way switch configuration, and not connected to the light at all.  Disconnecting it would rid you of the benefit of this configuration -- i.e. both switches would have to be on for the light to turn on.  With the red wire connected, either switch can turn on the light.

[image]

(A 3-way switch is an electrician's term for a single-pole, double-throw (SPDT) switch.)

Comment: A 3-way switch is an *American* electrician's term for a single-pole, double-throw (SPDT) switch. In Europe that's a two-way switch - up or down. In the USA they count the wires or terminals as "ways".

Comment: 3 ways to wire it and several ways to do it wrong including mistaking the Throw for the Pole.

Comment: Carter wiring e.g.

Comment: @Transistor since the OP specified American I tailored it to him.  If it were up to me I'd call it a two-way as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyAqv5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Note the switch closest to power source is lit all the time and remote switch is lit with bulb, due to internal light wiring on Pole or screw terminal furthest away.